# Problem starting a process with CreateProcess()

Tags: c, winapi, createprocess

The question is given like this:

> Using the CreateProcess () in the Win32 API. In this instance, you will need to specify a separate program to be invoked from CreateProcess(). It is this separate program that will run as a child process outputting the Fibonacci sequence. Perform necessary error checking to ensure that a non-negative number is passed on the command line.

I have done the following. It doesn't show any error message. When I try to execute it, it exits automatically:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  STARTUPINFO si;   
  PROCESS_INFORMATION  pi;   
  int a=0, b=1, n=a+b,i,ii;  

  ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));

  si.cb = sizeof(si);


  if(! CreateProcess("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe",NULL,NULL,NULL,FALSE,0,
                     NULL,NULL,&si,&pi))
    printf("\nSorry! CreateProcess() failed.\n\n");
  else{    
    printf("Enter the number of a Fibonacci Sequence:\n");
    scanf("%d", &ii);

    if (ii < 0)
      printf("Please enter a non-negative integer!\n");
    else
    {         
      {
         printf("Child is producing the Fibonacci Sequence...\n");
         printf("%d %d",a,b);
         for (i=0;i<ii;i++)
         {
            n=a+b;
            printf("%d ", n);
            a=b;
            b=n;
         }
         printf("Child ends\n");
      }

      {
         printf("Parent is waiting for child to complete...\n");
         printf("Parent ends\n");
      }
    }
  }

  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 5000);    
  printf("\n");

  // Close process and thread handles.    
  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

  return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood your exercise. Also, you might want to do handle inheritance while using CreateProcess. This might be above your skill level, but still a useful lesson:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q190351/

Answer (score 0):

Why are you invoking `cmd.exe` as your process? The problem states that it's the process that you're launching that should be printing the Fibonacci sequence. You shouldn't be doing it in the main process/app.

What you should have is a separate program that takes in a single argument and prints that many items from the Fibonacci sequence. You main program should ask for a number from the user and then launch the other program by passing in this number as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The question says to spawn a process that outputs a Fibonacci sequence. Get/validate the user input in the main process, then spawn another program (written separately) to print the Fibonacci sequence. Pass the user input to the spawned process as a command-line parameter.